# Store data required by a custom NiFi processor

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-nifi

HDP-2.5.3.0, NiFi 1.1.1

I am writing a custom processor in NiFi. There are several String and Timestamp fields that I need to store somewhere such that those are available on all/any nodes.

```
@Tags({ "example" })
@CapabilityDescription("Provide a description")
@SeeAlso({})
@ReadsAttributes({ @ReadsAttribute(attribute = "", description = "") })
@WritesAttributes({ @WritesAttribute(attribute = "", description = "") })
public class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
.
.
.
private List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors;
private Set<Relationship> relationships;

 /* Persist these, probably, in ZK */
private Timestamp lastRunAt;
private String startPoint;
.
.
.

@Override
public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context,final ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {FlowFile flowFile = session.get();

/*Retrieve lastRunAt & startPoint and use*/
lastRunAt ;
startPoint ;
.
.
.
}
}
```

Note that HDFS is NOT an option as NiFi may run without any Hadoop installation in picture.

What are the options to do this - I was wondering if Zookeeper can be used to store this data since it's small in size and NiFi is backed by ZK. I tried to find ways to use the Zookeeper API to persist these fields, in vain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NiFi exposes a concept called a "state manager" for processors to store information like this. When running standalone NiFi there is a local state manager, and when running clustered there is a ZooKeeper state manager.

Take a look at the developer guide here:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#state_manager

Also, many of the source processors in NiFi make use of this so you can look for examples in the code:

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-hadoop-bundle/nifi-hdfs-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/hadoop/ListHDFS.java#L249

Admin Guide for configuration of state providers:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#state_management